# Long FormulaArray - Compile Error for .Replace

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long array formula which I have split into 5 parts and when I ran the code, I was getting "Compile error, Method or Data member not found" highlighting .Replace in my code below.

***Update -*** I have made some changes to the code based on feedback. The code now runs, but it doesn't seem to take into consideration the formulas which need to be replaced in, i.e. all my results are the value of IF Error.

[image]

**DatabaseAP**

| Column G | Start_Date | End_Date | Product1 | Product2 | Final_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Account1; Account3; | 01/11/2018 | 01/01/2020 | 10 | 13 | Approved |
| Account2; Account9; | 01/10/2017 | 01/01/2019 | 9 | 14 | Approved |
| Account3 | 01/01/2019 | 11/11/2019 | 8 | 15 | Approved |
| Account13 | 01/01/2018 | 01/11/2018 | 7 | 16 | Approved |
| Account5 | 01/11/2018 | 01/01/2020 | 6 | 17 | Approved |
| Account6 | 01/10/2017 | 01/01/2019 | 4 | 18 | Approved |
| Account8 | 01/01/2019 | 11/11/2019 | 3 | 19 | Approved |
| Account14 | 01/01/2018 | 01/11/2018 | 2 | 20 | Approved |
| Account10 | 01/11/2018 | 01/01/2020 | 1 | 21 | Approved |
| Account11 | 01/10/2017 | 01/01/2019 | 11 | 22 | Approved |
| Account12 | 01/01/2019 | 11/11/2019 | 12 | 23 | Approved |

**DatabaseEX**

| Column G | Start_Date | End_Date | Product1 | Product2 | Final_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Account1; Account3; | 01/11/2017 | 01/11/2018 | 101 | 113 | Expired |
| Account2; Account9; | 01/09/2017 | 01/10/2017 | 91 | 141 | Expired |
| Account3 | 01/01/2018 | 01/01/2019 | 81 | 151 | Expired |
| Account1; Account3; | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2018 | 71 | 161 | Expired |
| Account2; Account9; | 01/10/2018 | 01/11/2018 | 61 | 117 | Expired |
| Account3 | 01/10/2016 | 01/11/2018 | 41 | 118 | Expired |
| Account7 | 01/01/2018 | 01/10/2017 | 31 | 119 | Expired |
| Account14 | 01/12/2017 | 01/01/2019 | 211 | 210 | Expired |
| Account8; ; | 01/11/2017 | 01/01/2018 | 111 | 211 | Expired |
| Account7; Account9; | 01/09/2017 | 01/11/2018 | 111 | 221 | Expired |

```
Dim O3P1 As String, O3P2 As String, O3P3 As String, O3P4 As String, O3P5 As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
                
O3P1 = "=IFERROR(IFNA(VLOOKUP(""*""&$X3&""*"",IF((W_W)*(X_X),DatabaseAP!$G:$BG,""""),MATCH($N3,DatabaseAP!$G$1:$BG$1,0),False),VLOOKUP(""*""&$X3&""*"",IF((Y_Y)*(Z_Z),DatabaseEX!$G:$BG,""""),MATCH($N3,DatabaseEX!$G$1:$BG$1,0),False)),""No BA"")"
O3P2 = "AU3>=VLOOKUP(""*""&$X3&""*"",DatabaseAP!$G:$BJ,MATCH(""Start_Date"",DatabaseAP!$G$1:$BG$1,0),FALSE)"
O3P3 = "AU3<=VLOOKUP(""*""&$X3&""*"",DatabaseAP!$G:$BJ,MATCH(""End_Date"",DatabaseAP!$G$1:$BG$1,0),FALSE)"
O3P4 = "AU3>=VLOOKUP(""*""&$X3&""*"",DatabaseEX!$G:$BJ,MATCH(""Start_Date"",DatabaseEX!$G$1:$BG$1,0),FALSE)"
O3P5 = "AU3<=VLOOKUP(""*""&$X3&""*"",DatabaseEX!$G:$BJ,MATCH(""End_Date"",DatabaseEX!$G$1:$BG$1,0),FALSE)"

With shtAnalysis.Range("O3")
          .FormulaArray = O3P1
              .Replace "W_W", O3P2
              .Replace "X_X", O3P3
              .Replace "Y_Y", O3P4
              .Replace "Z_Z", O3P5

.Range("O3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("O3:O" & lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
.Range("O3:O" & lastrow).Cells.Value = .Range("O3:O" & lastrow).Cells.Value

End With
```

Comment: How does `.Replace "X_X_X()", M3P2` know in which cell to fin the string `"X_X_X()"`?

Comment: Hi, I was basing it on the code I found here. 
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/long-array-vba-issue.853889/

Comment: As you can see in their `with`statement, it includes a range. `With ActiveSheet.Range("L2")` Start with that and see how far you get.

Comment: By updating the code to unable to:

```
   With shtAnalysis.Range("M3")       
        .FormulaArray = M3P1
        .Replace "X_X_X()", M3P2
        .Replace "Y_Y_Y()", M3P3
        .Replace "Z_Z_Z()", M3P4
        
    End With
```
I'm getting the error "Unable to set FormulaArray property of the range class"

Comment: The formula must be syntactically valid at all stages of replacement. Your `M3P1` is missing closing brackets.

Comment: I have made some changes to the code based on feedback. The code now runs, but it doesn't seem to take into consideration the formulas which need to be replaced in, i.e. all my results are the value of IF Error.

Comment: You seem to be thinking that Replace replaces one first occurrence. It replaces all occurrences, so you cannot replace the first X_X with one and the second X_X with another.

Comment: Sorry that was an error in typing. The first X_X was meant to be W_W. I have updated that here and on my macro. The issue persists.

Comment: Now that your formula enters correctly, you can [evaluate](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7) it to see where it fails. It fails because you have `vlookup(what, if(condition, here, ""), ..., false)`, and the `condition` is false, so you are telling it to lookup something in the range `""`.

Comment: It doesn't fail because of that, I have tried the formula by inputting it as an excel formula.